# Is there a character limit in the chromium DevTools console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the chromium DevTools console (the part where you input code to put into the current page), is there a character limit? If so, what is it?

Comment: Everything in software has a certain limit. Limit in which area exactly? A screenshot or more details please.

Comment: Like just a character limit for the console. (I know there is technically a point where it would stop working no matter what but im looking for a more reachable limit if there is one)

Comment: Iteratively paste `console.log('<your long string here>')` with longer strings until you hit a limit.

Comment: Console has several parts that can accept content so please elaborate what you mean exactly.

Comment: Sorry I'm like 10 days late, but I'm talking about the console input. Where you can enter code and where logged stuff appears.

Answer (score 0):

With current Version 122.0.6261.111 on my machine the limit is 9999999 characters (10 Mb).
From 10000000 to something above 500000000, I get truncated text, but it can still copy the text.
From this limit and onward, I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length
    at String.repeat (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:17
```

The last limit seems weird because it seems to change without corresponding to anything linked to a power of 2 or a power of 10.